# Can HOA force you to pay for services in addition to dues?

Tags: homeownership, hoa

My HOA (in CT) is asking owners to get their dryer vents cleaned. They asked last year and I obliged. I got them cleaned 12/18. They sent out an email today saying every unit must get them cleaned. I have used the dryer maybe 4 times since they were cleaned last, so the vents don’t need cleaning again at this time.

Can my HOA force me to pay $80+ for unnecessary dryer vent cleaning in addition to the $280+ monthly HOA fee/dues I’m already paying?

Comment: Do you have a copy of the HOA bylaws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be up to your HOA agreement. If you signed a contract agreeing to pay for services then yes. If not then no.

An HOA agreement is just a contract like any other and you would have to abide by what you agreed to.

Also, they may not have an actual contract for you to sign, but by moving to the community you would be agreeing to follow the by laws of the HOA.

If you have a disagreement with them that can not be resolved, you can let a judge decide in court, but that could cost more than just getting the service. https://www.wishtv.com/news/local-news/indianapolis-man-battles-homeowners-association-over-solar-panels/

So to sum it up, you can refuse but they have the right to take you to court if they choose. I would assume a judge would rule in your favor since it's an issue of what goes on in your own home, but there is really no way for anyone to say what someone else will do.

Comment: Yeah it’s not so much about the $80 (although every penny does count these days, especially for people dealing with medical issues) but the principal. I understand I agreed to be bound by certain terms, I just am concerned when stuff starts creeping in. If it was part of the contract or built into the HOA fees that’s one thing. But to start adding ancillary expenses on top that seem arbitrary seems out of line. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @stormdrain they may have a stronger (and more reasonable) interest in insuring that the dryer vents are clean than in insuring that they be cleaned.  In other words, they ought to be inspecting the vents or at least offering the possibility for you to demonstrate that they're clean rather than requiring you to clean them unnecessarily.

Comment: @phoog agreed. If they write back insisting I do it, I will insist they have the company they contracted come by my unit and inspect while they’re here working on other units. If the guy says it’s needed (same company as last year; guy seemed to be straight shooter), I’ll oblige. But I really don’t believe it will be necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @phoog also they mentioned in the letter they sent the other day that they did inspect and claimed all units needed cleaning. I don’t believe they did anything more than a cursory walk-by glance at the outside exhaust vent which is 20+ feet off the ground (upstairs/3rd floor w/d). I have cameras and am home often so I would have been alerted or noticed.

Comment: The HOA documents were there somewhere. *"the average property sale requires approximately 180 sheets of reports, contracts, forms, and statements"* [https://listwithclever.com/real-estate-blog/key-documents-required-to-sell-a-property/] - Probably bound to the property deed. People sign stuff without fully reading everything.